# Generating docx files with php using PHPDOCX

Tags: php, phpdocx

I guess no one was lucky to found the best solution of handling reports in php, specialy when it's a .doc/x report or file .... i searched for sometime and then i found phpdocx.com .. amazing php script, but it just doesn't work, and i don't know exactly where to find the output file ... and unfortunately the documentation doesn't help at any level ...

Now i need to know the way this script work .. i mean how results come out and become usable ... and what needs it take the script to work .. because it simply doesn't work on my local host .. i am using appache 2, php 5.2.6 ..

I don't actually need more than writing html with in ( a real doc format file, not rename a html file to .doc !! ), so if there is any solution ( without the COM Lib ... i am not on a windows server ) to generate real doc file with HTML .. please but it here

Thanks very much in advance :)

Comment: Can't help you there, but I cant give an advice: try to convince your costumer (or boss) to use PDF instead of .doc for reports. It will be easier for you to generate and users can view them without MS or Open Office :)

Comment: The problem with PDF that it cant be edited ... also i had many troubles with the fonts matter

Comment: Are/were you trying to create a doc or a docx? The documentation says you need Word running on your server to create legacy (doc) files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess no one was lucky to found the best solution of handling
>   reports in php, specialy when it's a .doc/x report or file

This is not the question corresponding to the title, but you should try [OpenTBS](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php).

It's an open source PHP library which builds DOCX with the technique of templates.

No temp directory, no extra exe needed. First create your DOCX, XLSX, PPTX with Ms Office, (ODT, ODS, ODP are also supported, that's OpenOffice files). Then you use OpenTBS to load the template and change the content using the Template Engine (easy, see the demo). At the end, you save the result where you need. It can be a new file, a download flow, a PHP binary string.

OpenTBS can also change pictures and charts in a document.

- [Demo page](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php?demo)
- [Documentation](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php?doc)

Answer (score -1):

The documentation of PHPDocX has been greatly improved.
Have you tried to look at the [PHPDocX](http://www.phpdocx.com/documentation/tutorial) tutorial?
You may also have a look at the Forum.

Comment: Please answer the question, that is what StackOverflow is about.

Answer (score -1):

```
require_once "Path of phpdocx library/CreateDocx.inc";

$docx = new CreateDocx();

$html = 'your data will store in this variable';
$docx->embedHTML(
    $html,
    array(
        'parseDivsAsPs' => true,
        'downloadImages' => true,
        'WordStyles' => array(
            '<table>' => 'MediumGrid3-accent5PHPDOCX'
        ),
        'tableStyle' => 'NormalTablePHPDOCX'
    )
);

$docx->createDocx($varPublicPath.'/word_export_file/example1_'.time());
// this is location where your docx file will generate(inside word_export_file docx file will store)
```